# Recursive algorithms for string operations

Tags: algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to write recursive algorithms for the following string operations:

1) An algorithm to reverse a string.

2) An algorithm to test if two strings are equal to each other.

3) An algorithm to check if a string is a palindrome (for example, "eye" or "racecar") - reads the same forwards and backwards.

I am fairly new to writing algorithms, so even examples of procedures/similar methods would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Induction Steps:** In each example, I'll show how to reduce the size of the problem by a little bit. You will need to do the base cases on your own.

- To reverse "abcd", just take the last character "d" and stick it at the beginning of whatever the reverse of "abc" is.
- To check if "abcd" equals "fbcd", just check that the last characters of each word ("d" and "d") match **and** that the remaining characters ("abc" and "fbc") match.
- To check if "racecar" is a palindrome, just check that the first and last characters ("r" and "r") match **and** that the middle leftover part ("aceca") is a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we have a function that takes two string parameters, say **first** and **last**, and it returns **last+first** as a string.

> function reverseString(first,last) {return last+first;}

So:

> reverseString('world','hello')

returns 'helloworld'.

Our string to reverse is say 'abcde', and we expect the result to be 'edcba'.

We might begin with a function call to reverseString, say;

> reverseString('a','bcde')

which returns 'bcdea'.

Now it gets technical - to perform a recursive call, we call reverseString() from **inside** reverseString(). We are going to assume that **first** is only ever $1$ letter long, and that the original call to reverseString() is of our required structuring.

> function reverseString(first,last) {
>
> output=first+output;
>
> while (length(last)>0) reverseString(last[0],last-last[0]);
>
> return output;}

Now there are loads of other computery things to do, such as make sure **output** is declared and initialized properly, and it has the correct scope, but these are covered elsewhere, for example StackOverflow.

And all the **output** values are still returned, but unless we 'catch' the value, they are ignored.

So:

> reverseString('a','bcde')

sets **output='a'** and calls:

> reverseString('b',cde');

which sets **output='b'+'a'='ba'** and calls reverseString('c','de');

So we then have:

> output='cba'. Call reverseString('d','e');
>
> output='dcba'. Call reverseString('e','');
>
> output='edcba'.

Now **last** is empty, so the original function call is terminated, and the returned value is 'edcba' as required.

---

To test if two strings are equal is not really recursive. To test for palindromes, reverse a string and see if it equals itself.